# FatalCrash when I click on a Button

Tags: java, android

I have this RemoteCar App which has the Buttons,

- "LOCK" -> leads you to another Acitivity.
- "LOCATION" -> leads you to another Activity.
- "START ENGINE" -> Lets you click on it and it changes the txt into
  "ENGINE RUNNING".
- "REFUEL" -> lets you refuel and increments my ProgressBar(FuelBar).

So the problem I have is that I can't click on START ENGINE or REFUEL anymore since the App keeps crashing for reasons I can not resolve, yet. I can easily click on LOCATION and LOCK those work perfectly fine.

Here I have the ErrorMessage:

```
    05-21 13:39:52.887 1869-1869/? W/gralloc_ranchu: Gralloc pipe failed 05-21 13:39:52.897 1869-1869/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0 05-21 13:39:53.097 1402-1429/system_process I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.example.schwarzerritter.remotecv02/.MainActivity: +546ms 05-21 13:39:53.297 1402-1429/system_process D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_unregister_buffer: exiting HostConnection (is buffer-handling thread) 05-21 13:39:56.857 1402-1486/system_process E/ThrottleService: problem during onPollAlarm: java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing stats: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/iface_stat_all: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) 05-21 13:42:00.387 1869-1869/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM 05-21 13:42:00.387 1869-1869/? W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa6661228) 05-21 13:42:00.387 1869-1869/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                         java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "AC : 18"
    at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
    at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:375)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
    at com.example.schwarzerritter.remotecv02.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:41)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
```

MainActivity.Java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public ProgressBar fuelBar;
    public Button lockButton;
    public Button engButton;
    public Button refuelButton;
    public Button plusButton;
    public Button minusButton;
    public Button locationButton;
    public SeekBar seekBarButton;
    public TextView seekText;
    int incFuel = 0;
    int acNum = 0;


    public void onClick(View v) {
        engButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.engB);
        refuelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.refuelB);
        fuelBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.fuelProgressBar);
        seekBarButton = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        seekText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.seekText);
        acNum = Integer.parseInt(seekText.getText().toString());



        switch (v.getId()) {
            case engB:
                if (engButton.getText() == "ENGINE RUNNING") {
                    engButton.setText("START ENGINE");
                } else {
                    if (fuelBar.getProgress() > 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Starting engine..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        engButton.setText("ENGINE RUNNING");
                        if (fuelBar.getProgress() >= 10) {
                            incFuel = fuelBar.getProgress();
                            incFuel -= 10;
                            fuelBar.setProgress(incFuel);
                            if (fuelBar.getProgress() < 100)
                                refuelButton.setText("REFUEL");
                        }
                    } else
                        if(fuelBar.getProgress() == 0) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No fuel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            engButton.setText("EMPTY GASTANK");
                        }else
                            engButton.setText("START ENGINE");
                }
                break;
            case refuelB:
                if (fuelBar.getProgress() == 0) {
                    engButton.setText("START ENGINE");
                    incFuel = fuelBar.getProgress();
                    incFuel += 10;
                    fuelBar.setProgress(incFuel);
                } else if (fuelBar.getProgress() < 100) {
                    incFuel = fuelBar.getProgress();
                    incFuel += 10;
                    fuelBar.setProgress(incFuel);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Tank is full",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    refuelButton.setText("FULL");
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    public void seek_bar(){
        seekBarButton = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        seekText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.seekText);
        seekText.setText("AC : " + (seekBarButton.getProgress() + 18));
        seekText.setText("AC : " + (seekBarButton.getProgress() + 18));
        seekBarButton.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            int progressNum;
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                progressNum = progress;
                seekText.setText("AC : " + (seekBarButton.getProgress() + 18) + "°");
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                seekText.setText("AC : " + (seekBarButton.getProgress() + 18) + "°");
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                seekText.setText("AC : " + (seekBarButton.getProgress() + 18) + "°");
            }
        });
    }

    public void lockPage() {
        lockButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lockB);
        lockButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent lockPage = new Intent(MainActivity.this, lockDoor.class);
                startActivity(lockPage);
            }
        });
    }

    public void locationPage() {
        locationButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.locationB);
        locationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent locationPage = new Intent(MainActivity.this, location.class);
                startActivity(locationPage);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        locationButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.locationB);
        lockButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lockB);
        engButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.engB);
        refuelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.refuelB);
        fuelBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.fuelProgressBar);
        fuelBar.setMax(100);
        fuelBar.setProgress(30);
        refuelButton.setText(R.string.refuelB);
        lockButton.setText(R.string.lockB);
        locationButton.setText(R.string.locationB);
        engButton.setText(R.string.engB);
        seekBarButton = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        seekText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.seekText);
        int acNum;
        seek_bar();
        lockPage();
        locationPage();

    }
}
```

Comment: There are so many reasons for why it could be crashing.  For example, the activity to which those buttons lead could have structural problems.  You should learn how to use a debugger and pinpoint the problem.  All anyone here can do is guess.

Answer (score 1):

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "AC : 18"
   at com.example.schwarzerritter.remotecv02.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:41)
```

You are trying to convert the string `AC : 18` to an integer in MainActivity.java line 41.

(Reading error messages helps)

Comment: the SeekBar is working perfectly fine and the value shown is also correct.

Comment: Since when is `AC : 18` a valid integer, and what has this to do with the SeekBar?

Comment: I did not say that it is a valid integer im saying that it is working perfectly fine. somehow it manages to convert the int into the string I dont know why and how but it works

Comment: I even removed the Integer out of the seekText and it is still crashing.